# Statements that will be legal or illegal in a Java class example with a declaration given

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I'll be honest right up front.  This is for a non-graded homework assignment for my Data Abstraction course in which I am struggling on these questions.

The textbook states:

Suppose you have the following class:

```
class Second {
     private int x;
     public int z;

     public int sum() {
         return x + y + z;
     } // end sum

     private void reset(int a, int b, int c) {
         x = a; y = b; z = c;
     } // end reset

     public boolean check(float x) {
          return x < 0;
     } // end check
} // end Second
```

Given the following declaration,

```
Second myClass = new Second();
```

indicate for each statement (which might appear in testing code) if it is legal or illegal (will cause an error).

a. `myClass.x = 5;`

b. `myClass.z = 5;`

c. `myClass.sum(x);`

d. `int ans = myClass.sum();`

e. `myClass.reset(1, 2, 3);`

f. `boolean x = myClass.check(11.2);`

---

I'm not looking for the answer per se, I am looking for an explanation for ME to arrive to those answers...I thought I could plug the class in and then make a test class including 12a - 12f and run it but I'm missing something.  I'm not even sure where the "Second myClass = new Second();" would be placed in the grand scheme of things.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would someone call the instance `myClass`? That seems needlessly confusing.

Comment: For method calls, consider whether the arguments being passed in match the parameters the method is expecting. For all parts, consider what [access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) the fields and methods are declared with.

Comment: I think `y` is missing in your sample code. If that's omitted on purpose, then the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: I'm not even sure where the "Second myClass = new Second();" would be placed in the grand scheme of things. You certainly need to know from where this is called as a lot depend on access modifiers in java. If this object is called from outside of your Second class, you cannot even run the first case a. which will be out of scope as x is declared private.

Answer (score 0):

This questions is testing your Java access modifiers knowledge ( What is allowed and what it not ). Java access modifiers are `public`, `private`, `protected`, `package-private`.

Comment: without capitals :)